# NearProtocol transaction commit, how to avoid InvalidNonce error reponce

Tags: nearprotocol

In same cases, there is an error on transaction commit like

```
{"code"=>-32000,
     "data"=>{"TxExecutionError"=>{"InvalidTxError"=>{"InvalidNonce"=>{"ak_nonce"=>58108599002462, "tx_nonce"=>58108599002462}}}},
     "name"=>"HANDLER_ERROR",
```

In the error response, the `ak_nonce` is equal to `tx_nonce`
The question what is wrong with nonce ?
How do avoid this error?

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

As you already marked, a cause of the error is really comes from tx_nonce and ak_nonce equality.

From [NEAR Protocol spec](https://nomicon.io/RuntimeSpec/Transactions#validation-with-state):

> Transaction nonce must be account[access_key].nonce + 1

I think, the problem appears owning to time, spent between getting last ak_nonce from blockchain and sending new signed transaction to blockchain.

As a result, workaround may be to increase ak_nonce not by one, but, for example, by ten. `account[access_key].nonce + 10`